# Insert Unicode characters through a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode

I have a code like below which calls to a SQL Server stored procedure

First name will be passed  a value like 电子邮箱

```
sCmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
sCmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

sCmd.Parameters["@FName"].Value = firstname;
sCmd.Parameters["@LName"].Value = lastname;
```

In stored procedure:

```
@FName nvarchar(200),
@LName nvarchar(200)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[testunicode]
       ([col1]
       ,[col2])
VALUES
       (@FName
       ,@LName);
```

But data is inserted as ???? even the table columns are `NVarchar(max)`;

I tried with adding 'N' before passing to stored procedure, and also the below. But still the same. What is the best way of doing so?

```
  Encoding tc = Encoding.GetEncoding("BIG5");
  byte[] bytes = tc.GetBytes(firstname);
  firstname = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)
```

Comment: have you tried reading it back? Coz it looks the right way

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with adding 'N' before passing to Sp

no need because the .NET String supports Unicode and it will take care of Unicode. If you see the request that is passed on to the database you will notice that **N'** will be affixed automatically.

> What is the best way of doing so.

You are doing it right. No need for passing in anything else.

> But data is inserted as ????

Check the datatype in your table. Is it really NVarChar?